# Reader doesn't return all rows from database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, xml, mysqldatareader

So i have a web api that presents values from my database. However i have 6 rows in my database, but it doesn't return the first row.

How do i get it to read and return all rows in my database?

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `CustomerDb`";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection;

        mySqlConnection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var listOfPlace = new List<Place>();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var Place = new Place();
                Place.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                Place.Name = reader["name"].ToString();
                Place.Address = reader["address"].ToString();
                Place.City = reader["city"].ToString();
                Place.Category = reader["category"].ToString();

                listOfPlace.Add(Place);
            }
        };
        return listOfPlace;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove if block.

```
if (reader.Read())
{
```

Comment: Thank you. But dont i need try catch exceptions then ?

Comment: why do you think so? but If you want to handle it for other purpose then you can use

Comment: Great! Thank you. Right now it returns on the in ascending order. How can i make it return in the order that i have made inside the loop (ID, Name, address, city,category)?

Comment: I didn't get your point. order does not matter here, by the way you can modify your query also to to define the order of columns

Comment: Oh yea! the query. I forgot. Thank you again sir :)

Answer (score 0):

The first `reader.Read()` inside if statement read the first row then while loop start from the second row so you need to remove the `if(reader.Read())` portion to read all data from the beginning

```
while (reader.Read())
  {
      var Place = new Place();
      Place.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
      Place.Name = reader["name"].ToString();
      Place.Address = reader["address"].ToString();
      Place.City = reader["city"].ToString();
      Place.Category = reader["category"].ToString();

      listOfPlace.Add(Place);
  }
```